# C++ argument COLORREF of type is incompatible with parameter of type char

Tags: c++, winapi

I am just trying to add a new function for a different parameter type.
The problem:

- when i receive string parameter as **address** as showen in example below works well, because GetTelStrParam function is correct
- when sending second parameter **user_color** as string HEX value #ffffff, i can not even compile because is saying **COLORREF of type is incompatible with parameter of type char**, i have paste below **GetTelStrParam** that is working for string, so need to do similar for COLORREF, as well i did **GetColorStrParam** and paste below wha i tried inside
- issue is on that line

  *GetColorStrParam(buffer, "USER_COLOR=", new_user.user_color, sizeof(new_user.address) - 1)*

Will appreciate any help how can be fixed function **GetColorStrParam** to return correct type, the function **GetTelStrParam** i paste as working example in order to be clear how works other types of parameters

Below will paste everything i have

```
int GetTelStrParam(LPCSTR string,LPCSTR param,char *buf,const int maxlen){
    int i=0;
    if(string==NULL || param==NULL || buf==NULL)  return(FALSE);
    if((string=strstr(string,param))==NULL)       return(FALSE);

    string+=strlen(param);
    while(*string!=0 && i<maxlen) {
        if (*string=='|') {
            string++;
            if (*string!='|') break;
        }
        *buf++=*string++; i++; 
    }
    *buf=0;
    return(TRUE);
}

// this is what i tried to do based on the GetTelStrParam fucntion above, but did not work, is saying COLORREF of type is incompatible with parameter of type char

int GetColorStrParam(LPCSTR string, LPCSTR param, char* buf, const int maxlen){
    int i = 0;
    int r, g, b;
    if (string == NULL || param == NULL || buf == NULL)  return(FALSE);
    if ((string = strstr(string, param)) == NULL)       return(FALSE);
    string += strlen(param);
    
    while (*string != 0 && i < maxlen) {
        if (*string == '|') {
            string++;
            if (*string != '|') break;
        }
        *buf++ = sscanf(string, "%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b); i++;
    }
    *buf = 0;
    return(TRUE);
}


int      GetTelStrParam(LPCSTR string,LPCSTR param,char *buf,const int len);
int      GetColorStrParam(LPCSTR string,LPCSTR param,char *buf,const int len);

char* MyCommand::execute(char* buffer, int* size) {

    UserRecord new_user = { 0 };
    GetTelStrParam(buffer, "ADDRESS=", new_user.address, sizeof(new_user.address) - 1); 
    // here is the issue
    // can not compile
    // error: COLORREF of type is incompatible with parameter of type char
    GetColorStrParam(buffer, "USER_COLOR=", new_user.user_color, sizeof(new_user.address) - 1);  

    // custom logic below
}

struct UserRecord{
   char              address[96];                
   COLORREF          user_color;                 
};
```

Comment: You declared `GetColorStrParam` to take a `char *` as third parameter, but you gave it a `COLORREF` (`new_user.user_color`). These are not related types at all. Why do you expect it to work? If you don't know C++ at all, how do you expect to write code in it? Go through some introductory book first. It shouldn't be all that difficult if you have knowledge of another programming language already.

Comment: It's worth noting that if not for the `MyCommand::execute` I'd have assumed this was C, there are lots of ways to do these things using idiomatic C++ that are easier and more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want something like this. This is untested code, and in any case you did not give any example input that you expect this function to work on, so it's hard to be sure if it is exactly what you are looking for.

```
int GetColorStrParam(LPCSTR string, LPCSTR param, COLORREF& buf) {
    if (string == NULL || param == NULL)  return(FALSE);
    if ((string = strstr(string, param)) == NULL)       return(FALSE);
    string += strlen(param);
    
    int r, g, b;
    if (sscanf(string, "%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b) != 3) return(FALSE);
    buf = RGB(r, g, b);
    return(TRUE);
}
```

You might need to replace this line

```
    if (sscanf(string, "%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b) != 3) return(FALSE);
```

with this

```
    if (sscanf(string, "#%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b) != 3) return(FALSE);
```

if your input data is in the form `#rrggbb`. As I said it's really not clear what your input data is.

Use it like this

```
GetColorStrParam(buffer, "USER_COLOR=", new_user.user_color);
```

You are going to find C++ hard when, it seems to me that, you are more or less guessing.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what i need, i build the solution and is working, the input is #rrggbb